# undefined reference to vtable after the creation of a class object

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I have the following two classes:

```
class Grill
{
public:
  virtual ~Grill();
  virtual std::string get_model() const{return _model;};
  virtual void set_price(float p){_price=p;};
  virtual float get_price() const {return _price;};
  virtual Grill* clone()=0;
protected:
  Grill(std::string m,float p):_model(m),_price(p){};
  Grill(const Grill& obj)=default;
  Grill(Grill&& obj)=default;
  std::string _model;
  float _price;
private:
  Grill& operator=(const Grill& obj)=delete;
};


class Grill_Charcoal final : public Grill
{
 public:
  Grill_Charcoal(std::string m,float p):Grill(m,p){};
  ~Grill_Charcoal(){};
  Grill_Charcoal* clone() override{return new Grill_Charcoal(*this);};
 protected:
  Grill_Charcoal(const Grill_Charcoal& obj)=default;
  Grill_Charcoal(Grill_Charcoal&& obj)=default;
 private:
  Grill_Charcoal& operator=(const Grill_Charcoal& obj)=delete;
};
```

In the main I want to create a `vector` that stores pointers to Grill objects. So I create `vector<Grill*>`. The problem is when I create an object. My main is:

```
int main()
{
   using namespace std;

   vector<Grill*> grill;

   Grill_Charcoal* gp=new Grill_Charcoal("adsaas",2312); //Error
   //grill.push_back(new Grill_Charcoal("Sdsaa",22)); //Error as well, not compiled

   return 0;
}
```

The g++ shows the following errors:

```
In function `Grill::Grill(std::string, float)':
program6.cc:(.text._ZN5GrillC2ESsf[_ZN5GrillC5ESsf]+0x1c): undefined reference to `vtable for Grill'
/tmp/ccjLugR9.o: In function `Grill_Charcoal::~Grill_Charcoal()':
program6.cc:(.text._ZN14Grill_CharcoalD2Ev[_ZN14Grill_CharcoalD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `Grill::~Grill()'
/tmp/ccjLugR9.o: In function `Grill::Grill(Grill const&)':
program6.cc:(.text._ZN5GrillC2ERKS_[_ZN5GrillC5ERKS_]+0x17): undefined reference to `vtable for Grill'
/tmp/ccjLugR9.o:(.rodata._ZTI14Grill_Charcoal[_ZTI14Grill_Charcoal]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Grill'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any explanation why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message spells it out for you ... you declared ~Grill() but you never defined it.